# Matching collection of strings

Tags: c#, .net, string-comparison

I have a `List<Product>` that contains 1000 products and a `List<string>` that contains 100 category names.

- The class `Product` has properties like `Name`, `Description` and `Keywords`.
- One of the sample value of the `Category` list is `Bags, Luggage & Travel Accessories`.

I am trying to match categories with the property values of the `Product`.

- I have tried Levenshtein distance.
- I also tried to split categories into words and check `.Contains(keyword)`.

What is the best way to do this?

```
if (_subcategory.Name == "Others")
{
    var _items = _category.Items.Select(s => new
    {
        Item = s,
        Match = GetStringMatchingPercent(s.Name.ToLower().Split(_separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Where(w => w.Length >= 3).ToList(), new List<string>()
        {
            deal.description.ToLower(),
            deal.title.ToLower(),
            deal.keywords.ToLower()
        })
    }).OrderByDescending(s => s.Match).ToList();
}
```

```
private static double GetStringMatchingPercent(List<string> keywords, List<string> strings)
{
    int t = 0;
    int d = 0;

    try
    {
        foreach (string s in strings)
        {
            foreach (string k in keywords)
            {
                t++;

                if (s.Contains(k))
                {
                    d++;
                }
            }
        }

        return d / t * 100;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Utilities.HandleException(ex);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the category stored in the description, keyword or name; are there other properties? Can the category be in any property?

Comment: @Matthijs 3 of them can possibly have the parts of the categories. If none exists then I need to mark it as "Others"

Comment: What specific issues do you have? Do you have string combinations that match when they should *not* be matching? Do you have string combinations that do not match when they should? Do you not get any matches at all? It is clear what you have tried, but it is not clear what you wanted to happen. If you could expand on the list of strings on both sides, with an indication which ones should match, the question may become answerable.

Comment: @LibinTK: Do you want to create a list with the Other-categoryitems or something? I can't seem to grasp what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question correct; you could use the following code:

```
List<string> categories = new List<string> {"Bags", "Luggage", "Travel", "Other"};

Product p = new Product();
p.Name = "MyProduct";
p.Keywords = "Luggage";
p.Description = "Some product";

Product p1 = new Product();
p1.Name = "MyProduct";
p1.Keywords = "Airport";
p1.Description = "Luggage";

Product p2 = new Product();
p2.Name = "MyProduct";
p2.Keywords = "Abc";
p2.Description = "Other";

List<Product> products = new List<Product> {p, p1, p2};

// Create a dictionary with a list of products for each category.
Dictionary<string, List<Product>> categorisedProducts = new Dictionary<string, List<Product>>();
foreach(string category in categories)
{
    categorisedProducts.Add(category, new List<Product>());
}

// Categorise the products.
categories.ForEach(category => products.ForEach(product =>
{
    string productString = product.Description + product.Keywords + product.Name;
    if (productString.Contains(category))
    {
        categorisedProducts[category].Add(product);
    }
}));

// Display all products with their category.
foreach (string s in categorisedProducts.Keys)
{
    foreach (Product prod in categorisedProducts[s])
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + prod.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Description: " + prod.Description);
        Console.WriteLine("Keywords: " + prod.Keywords);
        Console.WriteLine("Category: " + s);
    }
}

Console.Read();
```

Output:

> Name: MyProduct 
> Description: Some product 
> Keywords: Luggage 
> Category:
>   Luggage 
> Name: MyProduct 
> Description: Luggage 
> Keywords: Airport
>   
> Category: Luggage 
> Name: MyProduct 
> Description: Other 
> Keywords: Abc
>   
> Category: Other

What it essentially does is create a Dictiory which uses the supplied categories as keys; so using `categorisedProducts["category"]` will get you a list of products that are in that category.

You do have to fill it first, ofcourse. The comment describes where that happens. For each string in the categorylist, it searches the three supplied string in each available product. You could add other properties of Product to your liking.

At the bottem, it loops through all the products and displays their properties with the correct category.

Note: if more than one category appears in a product, it gets added to both. If no category is found, the product is skipped. `I have added "Other" as a category to make this work`.

Comment: my products was loading from RESTful API Services and that's why I couldn't post much code. You did understand my question. Is it possible to prevent products from being added to multiple categories and select the most relevent category based on the number of occurrences of the keyword?

Comment: That's fine. :) If this answer is correct for you, please mark it as such. If not, let me know so I can edit it.

Comment: and my categories aren't single word and that's why I used to split them into words and match them.

Comment: I think you can build that in yourself, can't you? Haven't I helped you enough to get the rest going? It is possible, but will take some work. And since you don't pay me.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Look around the interwebs for Jaro pattern distance matching. This should point you in the right direction. I have implemented this in various companies and when done correctly provides exactly what you're looking for and is very fast.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance

Cheers,
Rob